# How to map a function using multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've checked out map, apply, mapapply, and combine, but can't seem to find a simple way of doing the following:

I have a dataframe with 10 columns. I need to pass three of them into a function that takes scalars and returns a scalar ...

```
some_func(int a, int b, int c) returns int d
```

I want to apply this and create a new column in the dataframe with the result.

```
df['d'] = some_func(a = df['a'], b = df['b'], c = df['c'])
```

All the solutions that I've found seem to suggest to rewrite some_func to work with Series instead of scalars, but this is not possible as it is part of another package. How do I elegantly do the above?

Comment: It depends on what you functions are doing but typically you would do something like `def func(row): return row['a'] * row['b'] * row['c'] df.apply( lambda row: func(row), axis = 1)` ideally you want to write your function in a way so that it can operate on the entire series so it's vectorised, can you show what you are really trying to do

Comment: If for instance your function took `Series` as params then you could rewrite it to `def some_func(a,b,c): return a*b*c  df['d'] = some_func(df['a'], df['b'], df['c'])`

Comment: "some_func" is a complex function that makes a SQL call to fill the data, so I have simplified it here. I'm using df.apply as suggested.

Comment: Hello @ashishsingal, if you agree that my answer is correct, please could you [select it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for this question? Cheers, Tomas

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), as below:

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['a'], b = x['b'], c = x['c']), axis=1)
```

NOTE: As [@ashishsingal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132595/ashishsingal) asked about columns, the `axis` argument should be provided with a value of 1, as the default is 0 (as in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and copied below).

> axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> - 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
> - or ‘columns’: apply function to each row

Answer (score 18):

For what it's worth on such an old question; I find that zipping function arguments into tuples and then applying the function as a list comprehension is much faster than using `df.apply`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 3), columns=list("abc"))
def some_func(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c

# Using apply:
%timeit df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['a'], b = x['b'], c = x['c']), axis=1)
```

222 ms ± 63.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
# Using tuples + list comprehension:
%timeit df["d"] = [some_func(*a) for a in tuple(zip(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"]))]
```

8.07 ms ± 640 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Hi @toby-petty, can this method be used when the function is returning 2 values, which can be assigned to new columns of the dataframe.                                                                 
 df[['c','d']] =  [some_func(*a) for a in tuple(zip(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"]))]

Comment: Hi @ML_Passion, yes it will work exactly as you put it, so long as you change `some_func` to return 2 values instead of 1. Actually the `apply` method wouldn't work for the use case of adding multiple columns at once, it would need to be applied multiple times, making it even slower, so that's another win for this method.

Comment: Thanks a ton @toby-petty, i have a use case for this right now in my work. I want to wrap in a parallelize function using multiprocessing. Having some challenges but should be able to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

I use map that is as fast as list comprehension (much faster than apply):

```
df['d'] = list(map(some_func, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
```

Example on my machine:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 3), columns=list("abc"))
def some_func(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c

# Using apply:
%timeit df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['a'], 
b = x['b'], c = x['c']), axis=1)
```

130 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit df['d'] = list(map(some_func, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
```

3.91 ms ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Surely this is the difference between element and vector processing? Perfectly accurate if 'some_func' supports vector processing. However, the OP said 'some_func' was complex (including SQL calls) and did NOT support vector processing. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the following:

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['a'], b = x['b'], c = x['c']))
```

Seems to be working well, but if anyone else has a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice tip to use a list comprehension like *Toby Petty* recommended

```
df["d"] = [some_func(*a) for a in tuple(zip(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"]))]
```

This can be further optimized by removing the tuple instantiation

```
df["d"] = [some_func(*a) for a in zip(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"])]
```

A even faster way to map multiple columnns is to use **frompyfunc** from numpy to create a vectorized version of the python function

```
import numpy as np
    
some_func_vec = np.frompyfunc(some_func, 3, 1)
df["d"] = some_func_vec(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a really simple function, such as one based on simple arithmetic, chances are it can be vectorized. For instance, a linear combination can be made directly from the columns:

```
df["d"] = w1*df["a"] + w2*df["b"] + w3*["c"]
```

where w1,w2,w3 are scalar weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can also

```py
df['d'] = df.agg(lambda row : some_function(row.a, row.b, row.c), axis=1)
```

I think it is much faster than `df.apply`.