# Mapping over two columns in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes and I want one:

- first from PostgresSQL of some indexes: ['proj_id','detail_id','change_id']
- second is from excel ingestion: ['change_id','proj_id', etc...]
- result should be like this: ['detail_id','change_id','proj_id', etc...]
  As such:

  ```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'change_id': ['3', '4', '5'],
                      'proj_id': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
                      'detail_id': ['33', '34', '35']}
                      )
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({'change_id': ['3', '3', '4', '5'],
                      'proj_id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']}
                      )
  df_result = pd.DataFrame({'change_id': ['3', '3', '4', '5'],
                      'proj_id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                      'detail_id': ['33', '33', '34', '35']}
                      )
  ```

Each project has one id. Each project has multiple changes, and each change has a detail_id and change_id. ( I would say parent, child... step child?)
I would like to know if it is possible to map over two columns instead of one. 
Matching proj_id & change_id to a detail_id

I'd like to know if there is a way (or a better way) to tackle this problem.

Comment: I thought of doing a hackish, string concat of the two into one index and mapping that way, but again, hackish.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Unless I'm missing something, don't you just need to merge on `proj_id` ?

Comment: For mapping two to one, that was answered very nicely here - [How to map a function using multiple columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44648068/3698518).