# How to use map function to compare and fill in dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the json object like below:

```
lookup = [
  {
    "ID": "70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26",
    "Type": "A"
    "Name": "Galaxy Puzzle"
  },
  {
    "ID": "442B1598-20CF-4425-8A28-0438FBF77C46",
    "Type": "B"
    "Name": "Car Toy"
  }
]
```

And my dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, "A", "Galaxy Puzzle","TRUE"], [None, "B", "Car Toy","TRUE"],["4EB3D322-7A25-4A67-9053-28955383DD1F", "B", "Car Toy", "FALSE"]], columns=["ID", "Type", "Name","Enabled"])
```

Now I have to mapping ID from json object to dataframe base on Name and Type. Also it will ignore rows have ID in dataframe.

Below code from my last post help me to compare Name and ignore rows have ID but how can I **combine with other conditions** (in this case is Type)

```
df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "ID"] = df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "Name"].map({entity["Name"]: entity["ID"] for entity in lookup})
```

Please help me, many thanks to your help <3

Comment: Please share the expected output, it would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [map a function using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457149/how-to-map-a-function-using-multiple-columns-in-pandas) you may use `DataFrame.apply(,axis=1)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, "A", "Galaxy Puzzle", "TRUE"],
                   [None, "B", "Car Toy", "TRUE"],
                   ["4EB3D322-7A25-4A67-9053-28955383DD1F", "B", "Car Toy", "FALSE"]],
                  columns=["ID", "Type", "Name", "Enabled"])

lookup = [{"ID": "70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26", "Type": "A", "Name": "Galaxy Puzzle"},
          {"ID": "442B1598-20CF-4425-8A28-0438FBF77C46", "Type": "B", "Name": "Car"}]

lookup = {(entity["Name"], entity['Type']): entity["ID"] for entity in lookup}

df.loc[df["ID"].isnull(), "ID"] = df[df["ID"].isnull()] \
    .apply(lambda row: lookup.get((row['Name'], row['Type'])), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Giving the following (I changed a type in the `lookup` so you see it is well handled)

```
                                     ID Type           Name Enabled
0  70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26    A  Galaxy Puzzle    TRUE
1                                  None    B        Car Toy    TRUE
2  4EB3D322-7A25-4A67-9053-28955383DD1F    B        Car Toy   FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lookup)
df = df.merge(df2, on=['Type', 'Name']).assign(
    ID=lambda x: x.pop('ID_x').combine_first(x.pop('ID_y')))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Type           Name Enabled                                    ID
0    A  Galaxy Puzzle    TRUE  70B52DA6-F099-4D01-BBD0-03EA97292C26
1    B        Car Toy    TRUE  442B1598-20CF-4425-8A28-0438FBF77C46
2    B        Car Toy   FALSE  4EB3D322-7A25-4A67-9053-28955383DD1F
```

Comment: Hi @Nk03, what is ID_x and ID_y in your solution?

Comment: It's generated automatically when we do merge because both the dataframe contains `ID` column and it's not unique @NLeeT